# MongoDB insertion triples

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I try to insert new document to MongoDB collection, using PHP (Yii2):

```
$doc = [];
foreach ($this->fields as $field){
    if(Yii::$app->request->get($field)){
        $doc[$field] = Yii::$app->request->get($field);
    }
}
$response = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('responses');
$record_id = $response->insert($doc);    
echo $record_id;
```

When I check DB in RoboMongo, it shows 3 documents instead of one.
[image]
The `"echo $record_id"` outputs only one identifier, which is the fisrt in RoboMongo interface.

Why does it happen?

Comment: did you dump $doc before inserting ? what is the result ?

Comment: @KandarpPatel it outputs: array(4) { ["type"]=> string(5) "email" ["phone"]=> string(10) "7772723737" ["status"]=> string(7) "watched" ["campaign_id"]=> string(2) "12" }

Comment: strange .. is the request made via ajax ?

Comment: @KandarpPatel no, it's made directly from script. I also tried without any loop, but it triples everytime. BatchInsert also triples